How to create circular carousel with Swiper coverflow
Im not a Swiper expert. I'm using it for the first time, but I'd like to create a circular carousel like the one in the image below.
Basically I'd like to have a central camera and all the cards that moves around it.
I tried to create something with translate and scale but without success.
Any help is appreciated.



new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 7,
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true,
  on: {
    setTranslate: function () {
      const radius = 500;
      this.slides.each((index, slide) => {
        const slideEl = this.slides.eq(index);
        const progress = slideEl[0].progress;
        const scaleY = 1 + Math.abs(progress) * 5;
        const scaleX = 1 - Math.abs(progress) * 0.2;
        const offsetX = radius * progress;
        const offsetY = -Math.abs(progress) * 50;

        slideEl.css({
          transform: `
            translateX(${offsetX}px)
            translateY(${offsetY}px)
            scale(${scaleX}, ${scaleY})
          `,
          zIndex: Math.round(-Math.abs(progress) * 10 + 10),
        });
      });
    },
    setTransition: function (speed) {
      this.slides.each((index, slide) => {
        slide.style.transition = `${speed}ms`;
      });
    },
  },
});
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff7f50, #ff6347);
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, z-index 0.3s ease;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.6/js/swiper.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Card 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Card 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Card 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Card 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Card 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Card 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Card 7</div>
  </div>
</div>



